# multiple different wordpress logins for separate pages

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I'm trying to achieve the following with wordpress:

some url like www.somesite.com

I want to password protect different sections of the site and only allow certain users to access certain pages (I would manually set Username and Password)

example:

www.somesite.com/project1 would have a login to access that content
www.somesite.com/project2 would have a different login and wouldn't be able to access project1

...and so on and so forth

any ideas? I've looked at password plugins but haven't found anything quite right yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if this can be done with the existing roles in Wordpress or not.  Have you posted this question on wordpress.stackexchange.com?  You might have better luck on that section.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search over on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com, and I found that there's a roles plugin that you can use.  Have you considered this?  Here's a link:

im-web-gefunden.de/wordpress-plugins/role-manager

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTTP authentication for that purpose. You should configure it using your web hosting panel or htaccess file (there are many examples in the web).

Comment: originally I was thinking of just adding a .htaccess file to the password protected pages... but was trying to see if there's an easier way to manage / make new password protected pages

Comment: I see. You can use some PHP tool to manage .htaccess files (I don't know any, but there should be some).